# Find $m$ such that the inequality has $4$ integer solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms

> Find all values of $m$ such that the inequality: $\log(60x^2+120x+10m-10)>1+3\log(x+1)$ has exactly $4$ integer solutions?

The first thing I did was to gather from the inequality;

$\log(60x^2+120x+10m-10)>1+3\log(x+1)$

$\Leftrightarrow 1+\log(6x^2+12x+m-1)>1+\log(x^3+3x^2+3x+1)$

$\Leftrightarrow 6x^2+12x+m-1>x^3+3x^2+3x+1$

$\Leftrightarrow 0>x^3-3x^2-9x-m+2$

Right here, I have no idea of what to do next, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should mention in your question that $\log$ denotes the logarithm with respect to base $10$.

Comment: Why on Earth would anyone want to solve such a question? What is the motivation here?

Comment: But factoring $x^3-3x^2-9x+2$ might get you somewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "...anyone want to solve such a question?" : See my answer.  Even though the analysis is limited to preCalculus, there are subtleties around the definition of logarithms that make this an educational question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the inequality

$$m - 2 > x^3 - 3x^2 -  9x. \tag1 $$

As $~x \to -\infty, ~$ the RHS of (1) above goes to $-\infty.$

Therefore, it is tempting, but **wrong** to assume that regardless of the (**fixed**) value of $m$ chosen, there will be an infinite number of (**negative**) integer solutions.

The reason that this is wrong is that the original problem involves logarithms, and you can not take the logarithm of a non-positive number.  Therefore, there are two additional (hidden) constraints:

- $(x + 1) > 0 \iff x > -1$
- $(60x^2+120x+10m-10) > 0 $ 
  $\iff (6x^2 + 12x + (m-1) > 0$ 
  $\iff (36x^2 + 72x + (6m - 6) > 0 $ 
  $\iff (6x + 6)^2 + (-36 + 6m - 6) > 0 $ 
  $\iff [6(x + 1)]^2 > 42 - 6m \iff $ 
  $\iff 6 \times [(x + 1)^2] > 7 - m$ 
  $\iff m > 7 - \{6 \times [(x + 1)^2]\}$.

Further, given the problem's *preCalculus* tag, only purely algebraic methods of attack are permitted.

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 - 9x.$  Then, the range of $m$ must be identified so that there will be exactly $4$ integer values that satisfy all of the following constraints:

- $(m - 2) > f(x).~$ : Constraint-1
- $x > -1.~$ : Constraint-2
- $m > 7 - \{6 \times [(x + 1)^2]\}.~$ : Constraint-3

Then, considering Constraint-2 above, 
$f(0) = 0.$ 
$f(1) = -11$. 
$f(2) = -22$. 
$f(3) = -27$. 
$f(4) = -20$. 
$f(5) = 5$. 
$f(6) = 54.$

**Edit**
For $x \geq 6,$ you have that 
$f(x+1) - f(x) = (3x^2 + 3x + 1) - 3(2x + 1) - 9$ 
$= ~3x^2 - 3x - 11 = 3(x^2 - x) - 11 > 0.$ 
Therefore, for $x \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 6}}, f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

A natural try is to explore what happens if 
$(m - 2) > 0$.  
You would also need 
$m > 7 - \{6 \times [(x + 1)^2]\}$.

For $x \geq 0$, this will automatically be satisfied if $m > 1.$

Therefore, if $(m - 2) = 0$ then you will have the $4$ solutions of $x \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$

So, the question is, what happens if $m < 2$, or $m > 2 ~$ ?  $~~m > 2$ must be excluded, since that would automatically add the solution $x = 0$.

Note that $f(1) = -11.$ 
If $(x = 1)$, then you need that

- $(m - 2) > -11$
- $m > 7 - \{6 \times [(2)^2]\} = -17.$

Therefore, the **preliminary** answer seems to be

$$-9 < m \leq 2 \tag2 $$.

Note that if $m \leq -9$, then $x = 1$ is not a solution, $x = 0$ is not a solution, and $x \geq 5$ is not a solution.  Therefore, the range given in (2) above is the final answer.

Comment: Thank you. Will the method change using calculus?

Comment: @Snek In my opinion, Calculus would merely allow a more elegant investigation into the behavior of $f(x)$, based on examining the first derivative, $f'(x)$, and the 2nd derivative, $f''(x)$.  I suspect that one of the reasons that the original problem confined the focus to $x \in \Bbb{Z},$ was to ensure that preCalculus methods would be adequate.

Comment: I am struggling at the part "Note that $f(1)=-11$...". I don't understand why you tested $x=1$ but not the other values of $x$, can you explain a bit further?

Comment: @Snek  If you examine the values of $f(x),$ for $x \in \{2,3,4\}$ and also examine Constraint-1 and Constraint-3, it becomes clear that since any $x > -9$ satisfies Constraint-1 and Constraint-3 for the specific value $x=1,$ it must also satisfy Constraint-1 and Constraint-3 for any $x$ in $\{2,3,4\}.$  As far as Constraint-1 goes, it is because $f(1) > f(x),$ for any $x$ in $\{2,3,4\}.$  As far as Constraint-3 goes, it is because the lower bound on $m$ enforced by Constraint-3 **decreases**, as $x$ increases.

Comment: @Snek Previous comment has typo.  Should be "...since any $m > -9$ satisfies...".